# TYPO3/TypoScript - custom orderings in DataProcessor with FIELD()

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

Is it possible to set orderBy via TypoScript with something like: `ORDER BY FIELD(fieldname, value1, value2...)`?

if I simply set this:

```
uidInList = 59,56
orderBy = FIELD(uid, 59, 56)
```

I get this error.
[image]
The quotation marks aren't set correct and the "ASC" inside the `FIELD()` section isnt correct.

Then I tried:

```
orderBy.stdWrap = FIELD(uid, | )
orderby.value = 59, 56
```

This seems to be completely ignored due to the resulting query debugged in admin panel.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to use that because TYPO3 is handling every string part (divided with space) as one table field. If you strongly need that `FIELD()` usage, you need to use a userFunc or write your own extended DataProcessor.

Comment: Short and clear :) So I will go the custom Processor way. 
Thank you Thomas.

Comment: @OP Keep in mind that TypoScript is just a configuration array, advanced, but still.